# Issue in method anonymous class in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am making a GWT framework similar to Swing framework.

In GWT, I have one method in which I am making a anonymous class in method, but the problem is when this method executes, the execution control does not go to anonymous class instead it skips over it.

After this method executes completely, the control is transfered to the anonymous class. And this thing is working perfectly fine in Swing.

```
public void model(){
    System.out.println("This line is executing");
    DataListModel model = new DataListModel() {
        public void setRecords(List records) {
            System.out.println("I see this line after model() executes completely");
            int i = 0;
            records = new LinkedList(records);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("this line is executed without executing DataListModel.setRecords()");
}
```

Comment: can u paste code here. It would be more helpful

Comment: This code doesn't do what you say it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `DataListModel model = new DataListModel...` line doesn't actually execute anything. It creates a new instance, but unless either the `DataListModel` constructor calls `setRecords` (which it probably doesn't) or you use the `model` variable in some way that calls `setRecords`, `setRecords` will never be called.

Comment: thnks Ken for ur reply..........but it does executes DataListModel.setRecords() but only after model() executes...actually i am using logger in my project...nd my logger is showing that setRecord() is executing but only after model() executes completely that means setRecord() is called but it executes only after model() executed... I am getting Output like this... 
1. This line is executing 
2. This line is executing without executing DataListModel.setRecords() 
3. I see this line after model() executes completely 
Hope Ken u understand what i said